# Are %f and %lf interchangeable when using printf?

Tags: c, printf, double, floating, conversion-specifier

In an article on the w3resource.com, I've seen the following code:

```cpp
double x, y;
pr1 = sqrt(pr1);
x = (-b + pr1)/(2*a);
y = (-b - pr1)/(2*a);
printf("Root1 = %.5lf\n", x);
printf("Root1 = %.5lf\n", y);
```

The article says to take three **floating-point numbers**. But in their solution (this code snippet), they have used the `%lf` format specifier.
Why have they used `%lf` instead of `%f`?
Can I also use `%f` instead of `%lf` for floating-point numbers?

If I use a `float` keyword instead of `double`, and use `%f`, is there any issue?
The output is the same for me.

Comment: Your question should be complete without us having to go look at images.  Please include the code in your question.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168)

Comment: It depends.  If the context is `printf()`, then `%lf` and `%f` are interchangeable.  If the context is `scanf()`, then `%f` is for reading into `float` variables and `%lf` is for reading into `double` variables (and `%Lf` is for reading into `long double` variables), and the difference is crucial.

Comment: In `printf()`, `%lf` and `%f` are interchangeble because any variadic arguments of type `float` get converted to `double` by the *default argument promotion* rules that apply to all function parameters whose types are not specified by an in-scope function prototype. The same rules have no effect on arguments of type `float *` and `double *` (they are not converted to a different type), so `%f` and `%lf` need to be differentiated in `scanf()`.

Comment: A floating point number doesn't have to be of type `float`. This 3 types are all for floating point number: `float`, `double` and `long double`. Don't let the name confuse you. When you change from `double` to `float` you may lose some precision.

Comment: @Anik Sen, Tip: Avoid `"%f"` and `"%lf"`.  Use `"%g"`.

Answer (score 6):

`%f` has different meaning in `printf` and `scanf` family functions:

- in `printf`, `%f` and `%lf` are equivalent, and both are matched by `double`. This is because in variadic functions, all `float` arguments are promoted to `double` when the function is called, so there is no difference between passing `float` and `double` at a language level.
- in `scanf`, `%f` matches a `float*` and `%lf` matches a `double*`, and this distinction is very important.
  Using the wrong type of pointer will result in undefined behavior.

You can also use [cdecl+](https://cdecl.plus/?decl=scanf(%22%25lf%22,%20p)) to better understand `printf` and `scanf` calls.
The output is as follows:

> ```cpp
> printf("Root1 = %.5lf\n", x)
> ```
>
> ```
> Write "Root1 = "
> Write a decimal double with lower-case infinity/NaN symbols
>     precision: 5
> Write "\n"
>
> ARGUMENTS & EXPECTED TYPES
> --------------------------
> x (double)
> ```

When in doubt, use `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`, even in `printf`, where there is no difference between the two.
You will introduce pointless inconsistencies between your `scanf` and `printf` format strings otherwise.

##### Note on *floating-point numbers*

You may have gotten confused by the meaning of `float` and *floating-point number*.
`float`, `double`, `long double`, and more are *floating-point numbers* in C.
When the article says *floating-point number*, they could also mean `double`, `_Decimal32`, `_Float128`, etc.

##### Why doesn't `scanf` promote `float*` to `double*` similar to `printf`?

This is not possible, because the object in which we're storing the `float` cannot be used to store a `double`.

- At a language level, this would be a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/5740428).
- At an implementation-level, we would try to store e.g. eight bytes of `double` in a `float` which consists of four bytes, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> **l (ell)** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int argument; that a
> following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a long int
> argument; that a following c conversion specifier applies to a wint_t
> argument; that a following s conversion specifier applies to a pointer
> to a wchar_t argument; or **has no effect on a following a, A, e, E,
> f, F, g, or G conversion specifier**.

and (6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
> if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
> the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
> declared type. **The ellipsis notation in a function prototype
> declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last
> declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on
> trailing arguments.**

and

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does not  include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
> each argument, **and arguments that have type float are promoted to
> double. These are called the default argument promotions**.

Using the length modifier `l` with the conversion specifier `f` will only confuse readers of the code. Its using will arise questions. The readers of the code  will think that either the author of the code does not know that the length modifier has no effect or that without the length modifier a call of `printf` (or `fprintf`) will indeed have undefined behavior and using the length modifier is necessary.

As for using the length modifier with a call of `scanf` then the function deals with pointers of the type `float *` or `double *`. That is the *default argument promotions* are not applied to them. So to distinguish whether a pointer points to an object of the type `float` or to an object of the type `double` you have to use the length modifier `l` with the conversion specifier `f` with pointers of the type `double *` or without the length modifier with pointers of the type `float *`.

Adepts of using the length modifier `l`  with objects of the type `double` in calls of `printf` (or `fprintf`) only make code less maintainable because for example if the type of an outputted variable will be changed from the type `double` to the type `float` they will have to find and change all calls printf where the variable is used.

Comment: Obviously, this is very a opinion-based topic, but personally I find it better to use `%lf` for `double` consistently everywhere, even in `printf` where you could be more concise. *Technically*, you don't need to explicitly cast in a lot of places, but doing so conveys your intent clearly. Similarly, you don't need to use `%lf` in `printf`, but it conveys that you *intended* to print a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: @JanSchultke You are right. Low-qualified programmers prefer to write for example int x = ( int ) 'A'; or printf( "%lf\n", 1.0 );.:)

Comment: @JanSchultke Pay also attention to that the type of the outputted variable can be changed from the type double to the type float. In this case you will need to find and change all calls of printf where the variable is used.:)

Comment: I don't see any need in being condescending about this and calling them "low-qualified". C's type system is full of surprises and gotchas. The fact that `float` gets promoted to `double` when calling variadic functions isn't intuitive at all. In software development, it's much more important to have consistent rules that everyone will understand and follow, rather than saving *literally one* character to feel smug about your in-depth knowledge of `printf`. And having to update format strings when types of variables change is not limited to `float` and `%f`, it's a general refactoring problem.

Comment: @JanSchultke Even if to write a code for beginners (not professional code) then even in this case it is a bad idea to use %lf because beginners will think that it is required according to the C standard to use the length modifier with objects of the type double to avoid undefined behavior.:) Though even in books for beginners I have not encountered an advice to use %lf instead of just %f.:)

Comment: This isn't about "beginners", this is about collaborating on software projects and making sane style decisions. You can do no harm by using `%lf` when it's not strictly necessary, but you can do very real harm by copying and pasting a format string from `printf` to `scanf` if you're using `double` in your project, but chose to write `%f` for the sake of convenience. In the real world, no one cares whether you're a l33t developer who knows all the tricks for saving *literally one* character in format strings. People care about consistent, easy-to-follow rules that get the job done.

Comment: @JanSchultke I agree with you only in one thing that low-qualified programmers can make desicions about using bad styles of programming  that only confuse readers of code and arise questions to the code: whether programmers who wrote the code know about default argument promotions and that the length modifier l has no effect.:)